# Does Sitecore have a message queue?

Tags: event-queue

Does Sitecore have built in message queue that supports the batching of messages?  It looks like the event queue only supports single messages being passed to a handler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not out of the box. You could theoretically craft something on top of the EventQueue, but I would probably look to third party solutions.

- https://particular.net/nservicebus
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/

Edited to add:

- [Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) within an environment that includes Sitecore](https://alwebguy.blogspot.ch/2016/11/enterprise-service-bus-esb-within.html)

There are indications that Sitecore architecure will move in the direction that allows for easier adaptation and implementation of Service Bus technology. Not much is known at this point - even less not under NDA constraints - but Sitecore xConnect was presented at the 2016 symposium. From an architectural point of view, it sits right in the place you would normally think in ESB.

[image]

(Image source: https://twitter.com/m7mdSyam/status/776887493484511232)

Additional information; [Todd Mitchells presentation on xConnect at Symposium 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1osLdO5olw).

Comment: It might be worth updating this answer with information on Sitecore 9 / Sitecore.Messaging / Rebus

Answer (score 13):

In Sitecore 9.x There is a new message bus implementation based on [Rebus](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus) with an RabitMQ Transport Provider. This can be leveraged for your own custom requirements too.

It is used already in Sitecore 9 by:

- EXM Dispatch
- Marketing Automation
- xConnect

There is more info on this here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/message-bus.html

There is a good example of using it for custom requirements here:

https://www.pintle.dk/insights/using-sitecore-service-bus/

** Thanks to Pete Navarra for pointing out on Slack that more accurately there is a RabitMQ Transport Plugin running on Rebus.

Comment: It should be noted; Sitecore plans to abstract the actual Q implementation.